# The Wonderful Set

Tags: pattern, knowledge

What is the name of the set in which these elements usually are?

> {GPoG, HGoB, SoZaO, ToAaE, MaH, CoR, LoA}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> [Seven Wonders of the Ancient World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonders_of_the_World#Seven_Wonders_of_the_Ancient_World) :
>   - Great Pyramid of Giza
>   - Hanging Gardens of Babylon
>   - Statue of Zeus at Olympia
>   - Temple of Artemis at Ephesus
>   - Mausoleum at Halicarnassus
>   - Colossus of Rhodes
>   - Lighthouse of Alexandria

Comment: explain it a bit and I'll accept

Comment: I've added the names!

Comment: You answered too early. We need to wait 10 minutes. :p

Comment: Haha that's okay :) The name of the puzzle was a nice hint :p