# 4 sums of flags

Tags: visual, knowledge, flags

*The previous 'Sum of' puzzle can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31564/a-sum-of-images)*

---

[image: Flag] + [image: Another flag] = [image: Third flag]
[image: More flag] + [image: Hey! A flag!] = [image: Flag numero six]
[image: Surprise... A flag!] + [image: Flagapalooza] = [image: Flaaaaaaag]
[image: Boom! Flag!] + [image: Oddly shaped flag] = ?

Which flag should replace the question mark?

Comment: Since my work network blocks imgur, all I can see is your hilarious flag names. #worth

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is about the

> Dialing codes of countries.

So the answer is

> Australia [image]

Explanation

> 1. Portugal (+351) + the Netherlands (+31) = Montenegro (+382)
>  2. Japan (+81) + Taiwan (+886) = Yemen (+967)
>  3. Algeria (+213) + Argentina (+54) = Botswana (+267)

Therefore

> Egypt (+20) + Switzerland (+41) = Australia (+61)

Comment: Excellent! And quick! :)

Comment: @Wu33o [Just taking](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/31568/17482)... [the revenge](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30704/the-wonderful-set#comment91349_30705) :p :D

Comment: Hahaha, fair enough xD